# How to format following table to fit in page in Latex?

Tags: tables

I am try to add table to my Latex documet.

But table width goes out of page.

This is my code

```
     %table
 \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Implementation Assumptions and Dependencies}
    \label{tab: c4T1}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline \textbf{Assumptions} & \textbf{Dependencies} \\
    \hline  
        Private and Public keys share according to \newline secure exiting protocols. 
        & Video Stream Scanning Quality \newline depends on Mobile camera quality.\\
    \hline
            All keys Store secure manner in devices.  
        & Encoded data decoding depends on picture quality and another environment condition. (light)\\
    \hline  
        Assume media broadcast channel free of noise.
        & Encode and Decoding time depend on CPU power and Memory of machine and Mobile. \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
```

this is my out put.

[image]

I need  some expert to correct the output format as below.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\noindent% <-- important
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
 \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Implementation Assumptions and Dependencies}
    \label{tab: c4T1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
        \hline \textbf{Assumptions} & \textbf{Dependencies} \\
        \hline  
        Private and Public keys share according to  secure exiting protocols. 
        & Video Stream Scanning Quality  depends on Mobile camera quality.\\
        \hline
        All keys Store secure manner in devices.  
        & Encoded data decoding depends on picture quality and another environment condition. (light)\\
        \hline  
        Assume media broadcast channel free of noise.
        & Encode and Decoding time depend on CPU power and Memory of machine and Mobile. \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: +1. Please remove the `\noindent` directive, though, at it is in fact *not* needed at all. You could also remove the OP's `\centering` directive as it isn't needed either. Please also augment the code fragment so that it becomes compilable "out of the box", without any guesswork as to which packages may need to be loaded. (Yes, I do know that it's necessary to load the `tabularx` package. However, random future readers of your answers may not.) Finally, do consider adding a sentence or two to explain in words to readers how your answer accomplishes the OP's typographic objective.

Comment: error given ,'! LaTeX Error: Environment tabularx undefined.' and i also need ceter colum headers

Comment: @uma did you load \usepackage{ tabularx} -- i suggest you upload your code also rather than only snippets to have a succesful rendering/compilation -- secondly you need to read the comments given above by Mico

Comment: @jsbibra yep.Accroding to comment , i added package and remove that mention parts, it is working, but still couldn't 'center - cloum heder ;'Assumtions' and 'Dependency' , can you help me do it?

Comment: \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Assumptions}} --will center

Comment: if you want centering plus the vertical lines in the header rows use-- \centering\arraybackslash{\textbf{Assumptions}}

Comment: @Thank you... it working.